# Setting "Disable tiled raster layer exports" option to export to PDF using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, qgis-print-layouts

I need to use the setting `Disable tiled raster layer exports` from the GUI in my Python code, but I can't seem to find it.

```
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)    
exporter.exportToPdf(path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()` instance and set `rasterizeWholeImage` property of it as `True`.

```
layout_manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName('LAYOUT_NAME')

pdf_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
pdf_settings.rasterizeWholeImage  = True

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)    
exporter.exportToPdf(path, pdf_settings)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and while it did activate the option, it seemed to ignore it at export. I didn't see any difference. WMS tile lines still remained. What did work for me was using the option of PdfExportSettings()   rasterizeWholeImage=True. While not the best thing for everyone, it did the job for me.

Comment: I've just realized that I made a mistake. I editted the answer.